# Logic relating to Math.random() and ArrayList.remove()

Tags: java, math, random, arraylist

I'm wanting to assign random shirt numbers to girls on 20 soccer teams in a league.

**FIXED:  I ended up using Collections.shuffle(shirtnums) for each team and dealing numbers off the top.**

Here's the code I'm using to do that-

- I have an integer and an ArrayList:

  ```
  int shirtnum = 0;
  ArrayList<Integer> shirtnums;
  shirtnums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ```
- At the beginning of each team, I add the numbers to it:

  ```
  for(int number = 1; number < 31; number++){shirtnums.add(number);}
  ```
- At the end of each team I clear it:

  ```
  shirtnums.clear();
  ```
- And during the loop for the 22 girls, I'm trying to grab a random number and then remove it from the ArrayList:

  ```
  double shirt = Math.floor(Math.random() * shirtnums.size());
  shirtnum = (int) shirt;
  shirtnums.remove(shirtnum);
  ```

However, here's a sample output for one team:

```
pid lname       fname       DOB         posid   tid shirtnum
1   Smith       Mary        1997-09-05  1       1   23
2   Johnson     Patricia    1997-04-03  2       1   15
3   Williams    Linda       1998-03-03  3       1   10
4   Jones       Barbara     1998-08-14  4       1   13
5   Brown       Elizabeth   1998-02-24  5       1   13
6   Davis       Jennifer    1998-08-27  6       1   12
7   Miller      Maria       1997-09-06  7       1   2
8   Wilson      Susan       1998-03-02  8       1   16
9   Moore       Margaret    1997-01-04  9       1   2
10  Taylor      Dorothy     1997-04-01  10      1   11
11  Anderson    Lisa        1997-01-25  11      1   7
12  Thomas      Nancy       1997-08-05  1       1   1
13  Jackson     Karen       1997-01-18  2       1   8
14  White       Betty       1997-01-16  3       1   5
15  Harris      Helen       1998-06-12  4       1   7
16  Martin      Sandra      1998-07-08  5       1   13
17  Thompson    Donna       1997-10-11  6       1   11
18  Garcia      Carol       1998-03-06  7       1   7
19  Martinez    Ruth        1998-08-00  8       1   7
20  Robinson    Sharon      1998-02-20  9       1   8
21  Clark       Michelle    1997-00-00  10      1   2
22  Rodriguez   Laura       1998-06-12  11      1   3
```

Obviously, we can't have three #13's and two #2's running around on the field ... so what am I doing wrong?

By request, here's the complete code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GetSoccerNames
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{

    //declare variables
    Connection getconn  = null;
    Connection setconn  = null; 
    Statement getstmt       = null;
    ResultSet names_rs  = null;
    String lastname     = null;
    String firstname        = null;
    double year             = 0;
    double month            = 0;
    double day              = 0;
    String DOB              = null;
    int posid               = 0;
    int tid                     = 1;
    int shirtnum            = 0;
    int pid                 = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> shirtnums;
    shirtnums = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        getconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/playernames", "root", "");

        //setconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/league", "root", "");

        getstmt = getconn.createStatement();
        names_rs = getstmt.executeQuery("select fname, lname from names");

        //for each team
        for(tid = 1; tid < 4; tid++){           
            System.out.println("pid" + "\t" + "lname" + "\t" + "fname" + "\t" + "DOB" + "\t\t" + "posid" + "\t" + "tid" + "\t" + "shirtnum"); 

            //int[] shirtnums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

           for(int number = 1; number < 31; number++){shirtnums.add(number);}

            //for each player on the team
            for(int teamplayer = 1; teamplayer < 23; teamplayer++){
                //PID
                // print i value ... remove for insert
                pid++;

                //NAME
                names_rs.next();
                lastname = names_rs.getString(2);
                firstname = names_rs.getString(1);

                //DOB
                year        = Math.round(Math.random() + (2013-16));
                month   = Math.round(Math.random() * 12);
                day         = Math.round(Math.random() * 28);
                int yyyy = (int) year;
                int mm  = (int) month;
                int dd  = (int) day;


                        if (mm>9 && dd>9)   {DOB = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;}
                else    if (mm<10 && dd>9){DOB = yyyy + "-0" + mm + "-" + dd;}
                else    if (mm>9 && dd<10){DOB = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-0" + dd;}
                else    if (mm<10 && dd<10){DOB = yyyy + "-0" + mm + "-0" + dd;}

                //POSID
                posid = ((pid-1)%11)+1;

                //TID
                //tid is determined outside the loop

                //SHIRTNUM
                double shirt = Math.ceil(Math.random() * shirtnums.size());
                shirtnum = (int) shirt;
                shirtnums.remove(shirtnum - 1);


                //TEST PRINT
                System.out.println(pid + "\t" + lastname + "\t" + firstname + "\t" + DOB + "\t" + posid + "\t" + tid + "\t" + shirtnum); 
            }
            shirtnums.clear();
        }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.out.println("Class Not Found: " + cnfe.getMessage());        
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        System.out.println("SQL Error: " + sqle.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if (getconn != null)        try{getconn.close();}       catch(SQLException ignore){}
        if (getstmt != null)        try{getstmt.close();}       catch(SQLException ignore){}
        if (names_rs != null)       try{names_rs.close();}          catch(SQLException ignore){}
    }
}
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: please share the complete code

Comment: The problem seems to be, you are resetting the `shirtnums` for each girl's loop which means you are loosing information about the previously used shirt nums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

In this way:

```
Collections.shuffle(shirtnums, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
```

Then you can simply iterate through the shuffled list:

```
for(Integer shirtnum : shirtnums) {
    ... etc
}
```

You can do this for each team.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Collections.shuffle(List<?>)`  Shuffle all thirty-three numbers and deal off the top?

```
private void assignJerseys(int availableJerseys, List<Player> players) {

    assert players.size() < availableJerseys : "Not enough jerseys.";
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= jerseys; ++i {
       numbers.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    for (int p = 0; p < players.size(); ++p) {
        players.get(p).setJerseyNumber(numbers.get(p));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's too bad that you can't shuffle a `Stack`, as that doesn't implement `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the random number for the shirt number directly, instead of the array contents.

You should retrieve your shirt number from the contents of the array instead of directly from the random number.

```
shirtnum = shirtnums.remove((int) shirt);
```

Comment: So I should remove 
    (shirtnum-1)?

Comment: That's throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: Hmm, can you please post your whole loop for me then?

Comment: I did.  Thanks for looking and helping.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the shirtnumber has been removed already from the list before assigning it to the player. A check if the random shirt number generated would solve your problem.